# how can I adding page break just if needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the following code with many tables which are dynamic in nature:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        ...
    </table>  
    <table>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
 ...more tables
</div>
```

when I am printing the div element using javascript/ jquery, some of the tables are cut in the middle.

I try to use CSS (page-break-after / page-break-before) but then i get each table in separate page.

in addition, the height of each table is different for each user so we can't know the height of the table beforehand !!

Is there any way to break page just when needed ? just to prevent splitting ?

Comment: `we can't know the height of the table beforehand` Just wanted to say that you can always get the current height with JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed but you don't close your `<table>` tags. If you have `HTML` problems or if you are not sure if it's correct, validate your `HTML` page @ https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input AND please if you write code, do it correct!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in **CSS**:

Requirement : Avoid breaks inside the table/row

```
<style type="text/css">
table tr,table th {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}    
table {
    page-break-after: auto;
}
</style>
```

You can read more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/#s.8.2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its NOT working for me :/

Comment: When would you like to break? And when not?

Comment: if there is a place for the whole table so I don't want to break but if there isn't a place for the table so add a break and than put that table in a beginning of a new page. so I could have 4 tables in one page and 1 table in another and so on...

Comment: table {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
table { 
  display:block; 
  page-break-inside:auto;
}
tr { 
  page-break-inside:avoid; 
  page-break-after:auto; 
}
```